# JQUERY gotcha, Why can't I change inside an iframe that is hosted locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe, live

Give the following on a page:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" tabindex="0" src="" title="Rich text editor" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="hi-world">
<p><span class="tipoff" title="System tooltip for search engines">Download now</span></p><p>adasdads</p><p>a</p><p><span class="tipoff" title="System tooltip for search engines">Download n1111ow</span></p>
</iframe>
```

The following works:

```
$('#hi-world').css("width","10px");
```

But what I want to do is change the paragraphs in the iFrame, and this does not work:

```
$('#hi-world').find('p').css("background","red");
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. That's not how you put content in an `<iframe>`. An `<iframe>` creates a separate window embedded in the outer window. You have to load its content via an HTTP request.

Comment: @Pointy, actually iframes are completely scriptable, as long as it's same-domain.

Comment: They're *scriptable*, sure; that's not what I meant.  I was referring to the "content" in the `<iframe>` in the markup. Maybe that works, and if so it wouldn't be the first time something on SO amazed me.

Comment: @Pointy.  Sorry, I misunderstood your point.  You're right that the hard-coded child elements will not usually display.  One obvious exception is if the iframe tag is unrecognized (or possibly disabled).

Answer (score 4):

ok just figured it out:

```
$('#hi-world').contents().find('p').css("background","red");
```

Comment: Note: You can accept your own answer (once the time limit's up)

Answer (score 1):

The first is changing the css of the iframe element.  To do the second, you have to access the [contentDocument](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/dom/domref/dom_frame_ref4.html).  As noted, in jQuery you can use [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) for this.